# RTSP to HLS with audio

Tags: java, gstreamer, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I am trying to perform RTSP to HLS conversion using GStreamer for that purposes I created a pipeline that works fine with the video channel, but the audio seems to be lost. Is there a way to include the audio channel to the HLS playlist?

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.112.86:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5 playlist-location=/hlssink/playlist.m3u8 location=/hlssink/segment%05d.ts target-duration=10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make another connection between your rtsp source and the muxer. For AAC audio for example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc name=myrtsp location=rtsp://192.168.112.86:8554/test ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mymux ! hlssink max-files=5 playlist-location=/hlssink/playlist.m3u8 location=/hlssink/segment%05d.ts target-duration=10 myrtsp. ! queue ! rtpmp4adepay ! aacparse ! mymux.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i ran it i've got an error message 

WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:myrtsp: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:myrtsp:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstRTSPSrc named myrtsp to some pad of GstQueue named queue1

Comment: So maybe your audio codec is sometheing else and you need other elements hooked up..  not sure

Comment: thanks Floria you're right audio was in mp4 format i succeeded when i changed the pipeline to 


gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc name=myrtsp location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mymux ! hlssink max-files=5 playlist-location=/hls/test/playlist.m3u8 location=/hls/test/segment%05d.ts target-duration=10 myrtsp. ! queue ! rtpmp4gdepay ! mymux.

Comment: Oh good catch. I thought `mp4a` is the more common one.. but it has been a long time.. perhaps using `parsebin` would have been a more versatile approach.

Comment: i'll try to test this out, need to update the version of gstreamer first, parsebin has become available since 1.10 release